# Cannot forward.Response already committed. Error

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am calling a servlet from jsp using

```
//My servlet code is:
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
       {
           String template="test";   
           abcViewBean punchOutCan = new abcViewBean();
           punchOutCan.setPunchOutCanonicalRes(template);
           try {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/PunchOutCanonicalError.jsp").forward(request,response);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }
```

My JSP code is:

```
<jsp:include page="/PunchOutCanonicalServlet" flush="true"/>  
<c:out value="${punchOutCan.punchOutCanonicalRes}" />
```

Please suggest, how to get rid of this.

Answer (score 1):

Exclude (remove) this statement from `doGet` of servlet because you're importing the response in JSPs.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/PunchOutCanonicalError.jsp")
    .forward(request,response);
```

doGet must be:

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                  HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException,IOException{
       String template="test";   
       abcViewBean punchOutCan = new abcViewBean();
       punchOutCan.setPunchOutCanonicalRes(template);
       //You can push the bean object into request via setAttribute
       //e.g
       //request.setAttribute("punchOutCan",punchOutCan);
}
```

And JSP Code,

```
<jsp:include page="/PunchOutCanonicalServlet" flush="true"/>  
<c:out value="${punchOutCan.punchOutCanonicalRes}" />
```