# How can I pass object from servlet to JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass an Object from the servlet to the calling JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033092/how-to-pass-an-object-from-the-servlet-to-the-calling-jsp)

How can I pass object from servlet to JSP?

I have used the following code in the servlet side

```
request.setAttribute("ID", "MyID");
request.setAttribute("Name", "MyName");
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("MangeNotifications.jsp");  
if (dispatcher != null){  
dispatcher.forward(request, response);  
}
```

and this code in JSP side

```
    <td><%out.println(request.getAttribute("ID"));%> </td>
    <td><%out.println(request.getAttribute("Name"));%> </td>
```

I get null results in the JSP Page

Comment: What did you try? Where did you fail? What where you expecting? What did you get?

Comment: dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033092/how-to-pass-an-object-from-the-servlet-to-the-calling-jsp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033092/how-to-pass-an-object-from-the-servlet-to-the-calling-jsp/12033175#12033175

Comment: @user1576197 - Is this servlet code  in doGet or doPost?

Comment: doGet and I have check it in doPost and I get the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think servlet's service (doGet/doPost) method is not requested. In order to access *request* attributes in JSPs, you *must* request the `servlet` via `url-pattern` and that way you don't have to use session.

SampleServlet.java

---

```
@WebServlet(name = "SampleServlet", urlPatterns = {"/sample"})
public class SampleServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
   request.setAttribute("ID", "MyID");
   request.setAttribute("Name", "MyName");
   RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request
                       .getRequestDispatcher("/MangeNotifications.jsp");  
   if (dispatcher != null){  
      dispatcher.forward(request, response);  
   }
  }
}
```

MangeNotifications.jsp  (I presume that this file is located at root of web-context)

---

```
<br/>ID : ${ID}     Or scriptlets  <%-- <%=request.getAttribute("ID")%>  --%> 
<br/>ID : ${Name}
```

Now open the browser and set request url somersetting like this,

```
http://localhost:8084/your_context/sample
```

Comment: If you request `MangeNotifications.jsp` then it will be empty and if you request via servlet-url then it *must* not an empty.

Comment: Still empty even I use the servlet URL

Answer (score 1):

Put it in the session (`session.setAttribute("foo", bar);`) or in the request; then it is accessible from the JSP through the name you gave it ("foo" in my example).

EDIT :
Use simply `<%= ID %>` and `<%= Name %>` instead of `<%out.println.....%>`. Note the `=` at the beginning of the java tag, indicating to output the result of the expression.

Comment: You access it the wrong way, I edited my answer.

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 27 in the jsp file: /MangeNotifications.jsp
ID cannot be resolved to a variable
24:     </tr>
25:   
26:     <tr> 
27:         <td> <%=ID%></td>
28:         
29:       <td> </td>
30:       <td>&nbsp;</td>

Comment: You're confusing `<%= %>` with `${}`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info